# In PhD admissions, if a correspondence is opened with a prospective student, is it common for a professor to just stop replying?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, professorship

If a prospective student contacts a professor about his/her work or group and the professor engages (asking for more info, acknowledging the student's existence ;-), etc), is it common for the replies to just stop? I would think courtesy at least calls for the standard easy let down, e.g "Perhaps we should talk after the admissions process," but on the other hand I understand how busy professors are and how spammy prospective students can be.

So I ask those of you "in the know," if you've engaged a student, do you feel inclined to at least let them know you will not be responding anymore? Or do you ultimately just find it easier to not respond (for example if the info you asked for isn't up to snuff)?

(I'm specifically asking about CS/ENG people, but any discipline is free to respond)

Comment: I'll admit that I sometimes just stop because my e-mail becomes overwhelming. Yes, it's a great idea for faculty to give a "let down" but it doesn't always happen.

Comment: Often there isn't anything to continue. Student says HELO; prof sends ACK and REQ for more info; student sends info; prof can send ACK but there isn't any other REQ and student doesn't have a REQ. Protocol isn't clear as to whether a FIN/END message should be sent by either party.

Comment: Yeah I hear you. But when the student send the requested info, should you provide feedback? Not necessarily like "You look like a great/terrible candidate," but rather "Thanks for the information, I will do X, Y, Z with it" or something. If only to clarify why you asked

Comment: Although we sometimes do so, it is not the job of professors to correspond with prospective students.  The program office or maybe graduate admissions office does that.

Comment: At least with all the departments in the USA that I'm familiar with, doctoral grad admissions **are** done by faculty in the department and not by any central office.

Comment: @geoff - We'll read it to form a better opinion of the candidate, but I would like to assume that the candidate knows that already?

Comment: @RoboKaren I'm thinking based on this question that a FIN/END on the part of the prof would be appreciated by the student. Nice summary. :-)

Comment: But we don't know if the client has any more requests. It'd be nice if there was a status code (aka reply format) that temporarily tore down the connection without suggesting that the channel was permanently closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a faculty member, I try to respond to all prospective students but many times the questions are too vague, tautological, or impossible to answer:

- Will I get in? Impossible to answer.
- Will you work with me if I get in?
  Tautological. If you are in my field of study and you get in, it's likely because I want to work with you. But I don't want to say yes because that may be misread as saying that we *will* accept you.
- What are the strengths and weaknesses of your program? Not easily answerable, self-serving if I deem my own area strong and likely to insult faculty in the areas I deemed week.
- Tell me more about your research. Too open ended. My CV is online.

I don't mean to sound harsh but questions that can be easily answered are the most likely to get responses.

Faculty do welcome e-mails from prospective students, especially those in our fields. When you get 150+ applications, it might be easy to miss someone in your specific area, so a personal message saying that you are applying is always welcome (especially early in the semester --- Sept or Oct -- before things get crazy).  Questions that aren't answerable on our website are also welcome (for example, not all department websites list which students are associated with which faculty; asking about our team members in those cases is welcome).

If you pique our interest (and we have the time), we may ask for further info from you -- for example, a paper you wrote or other writing sample. While I try to send a simple "thanks" ack message to these responses, I may be asking for something in November that I won't look at seriously until February with the other application material. So don't take the lack or brevity of acknowledgement to mean anything significant.

Note that we may not want to send an e-mail prematurely closing down discussion as we may feel that this is rude to an applicant who may have more questions. So we are in essentially a typical asynchronous communication hang condition.

That being said, I do often wish that I could respond in http status codes:

```
100 continue
200 ok
303 see other
307 temporary redirect
402 payment required
404 resource not found
406 not acceptable
412 precondition failed
417 expectation failed
503 service unavailable
```

Comment: Are there examples of questions you do consider appropriate?

Comment: Asking about our grad students is welcome. My department website is crappy and you wouldn't be able to find which grad students are working with me (or with other faculty). If you would like to chat with them, I'd be happy to pass along their names. In http status codes, that'd be a 303/307 response. :-)

Answer (score 5):

My experience as a PhD student would lead me to believe that sometimes professors get bogged down in the process of teaching classes, writing research grants, doing/planning research and all the other day to day activities that their institution demands of them.

I would think you are the low person on the totem pole at this point. That might be different if you were a rising star but the vast majority of us are not recruited, we apply for admission. I might send one last email and in it let them know that you just wanted to check in and relate that you completely understand the time constraint they are under but you would like to make sure they had received what ever you had sent and if they were to busy that was fine and to just contact you when they had the time at a much later date.

Answer (score 4):

> If a prospective student contacts a professor about his/her work or group and the professor engages (asking for more info, acknowledging the student's existence ;-), etc), is it common for the replies to just stop? I would think courtesy at least calls for the standard easy let down
>   do you feel inclined to at least let them know you will not be responding anymore? Or do you ultimately just find it easier to not respond (for example if the info you asked for isn't up to snuff)?
>
> In an ideal world, yes, but you are contacting us, asking us to take time to engage with you. If we did this for every applicant, it would require many hours per week of work, on a task we did not initiate. Declining a student is also not pleasant and a non-answer is often substituted.

Some information you, and others, might find helpful:

Professors, like most people these days, receive many emails daily. We would love to receive emails from prospective students looking to work with us when they are high quality students and a good fit to our needs. The problem is that too many of the emails are "fishing," and are a waste of our time. That sours us (or at least me) on the others before we even read them. Sometimes I try to be courteous and reply before filing the email, and hope to receive some information that indicates this student is a good fit. Sometimes I have nothing more I can add at that point in time, and am waiting hoping that I will later. Sometimes the emails just get lost in the queue after the student responds.

From my experience:

- Many of these prospective student emails are written using poor grammar, or very informal speech. This indicates the student is not serious about this pursuit. I only want students capable of high quality professional work. If the letter asking for a position (=asking for a job) is poorly written or very informal, what will the student's work be like if invited to join my team?

  Many emails indicate the candidate has not done his/her homework. I am a female professor (in "CS/ENG") and receive many emails addressed "Dear Sir." Those students never looked at my webpage. My picture is there. I want a student who is capable and motivated enough to do his/her homework. If he/she isn't going to work hard when asking for admissions/funding, what does that indicate about the level of effort the student will expend when pursuing the degree?

  Many emails say the student wants to work in my field, but the listed area of interest, or the examples of areas of past work, are not in my field. Some students write to every professor in the department saying that field is his/her interest (we do talk with each other). Being flexible is good, but the PhD is a targeted field of study. This also indicates lack of sincerity, and lack of industriousness.

  Many emails are simply trying to get past the admissions committee hoping for funding. I usually don't know if I will have funding in the coming year. I am not in control of the funding the department will offer. I certainly can't promise anything far in advance, and won't promise it right away. I am much more likely to take a student who has applied and has passed the admissions committee and fund that student, if I have funding available to grant. If the student has really impressed me by a good introduction, and follows up professionally, his/her chances greatly improve.
  Hint: Often funding comes right when the school year starts, or a student who was in line to receive funding doesn't come opening a department funded slot.  Unfunded admitted students are likely to be funded at that time.

Suggestions:

- Write a very professional letter.

  Do your homework:

  - In what area does the professor work?

    What courses does the professor
       teach?

    What papers has the professor written recently?

    What work is
       still open related to those papers?

    Is it an area you are truly
       interested in?

    What skills and background do you offer that would
       make it worth expending more of our effort to recruit you, and the significant effort to advise you once admitted? This needs
       to be more than just having earned a BS or BS/MS with decent grades.

    Can you show me that you are industrious and capable of advanced work by showing an interest that is not superficial?

  Write a targeted letter.

  Proof read the email.

  Have a friend proof read the email.

  Proof read the email again.

Good luck.